# How to fill a combo box with values from two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns in an Excel Sheet with headers (Surname, Name). I created a combo box and I enabled the ColumnHeads property. I would like to fill this combo box with these two columns.
My problem is that I do not know how to add the second column below the first one like the image. In the ListFillRange I wrote B3:C4 but it did not work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of directly doing this, but you could either with a macro, OR you could insert a formula column to concatenate the two and point to that as your data source (you could use a named range based on an OFFSET formula to dynamically size the list rather than showing blank entries). Set the text to a white color to hide the concatenation results and keep things looking pretty.